# How to hide the page number of subsections in the table of contents (TOC) in revTex?

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, page-numbering, sections-paragraphs, revtex

I would like to display the page numbers in the table of contents of the sections only in revTex. Please here is a minimal working environment:

```
\documentclass[aps]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection of first section}
\subsection{Second subsection of first section}

\section{Second section}
\subsection{First subsection of second section}
\subsection{Second subsection of second section}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

I.e. only the page number for the first and second sections should be displayed. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,

hartmut

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The revtex4-1 class uses the same format for every line the the toc, just changing the indentation.  You could reduce the clutter using etools, but the net effect will be the same.

```
\documentclass[aps]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 

\makeatletter
\def\l@@sections#1#2#3#4{%
 \begingroup
  \everypar{}%
  \set@tocdim@pagenum\@tempboxa{#4}%
  \def\testA{subsection}\def\testB{#2}\ifx\testA\testB \set@tocdim@pagenum\@tempboxa{}\fi% one line patch
  \global\@tempdima\csname tocdim@#2\endcsname
  \leftskip\csname tocleft@#2\endcsname\relax
  \dimen@\csname tocleft@#1\endcsname\relax
  \parindent-\leftskip\advance\parindent\dimen@
  \rightskip\tocleft@pagenum plus 1fil\relax
  \skip@\parfillskip\parfillskip\z@
  \let\numberline\numberline@@sections
  \@nameuse{l@f@#2}%
  \ignorespaces#3\unskip\nobreak\hskip\skip@
  \hb@xt@\rightskip{\hfil\unhbox\@tempboxa}\hskip-\rightskip\hskip\z@skip
  \expandafter\par
  \expandafter\aftergroup\csname tocdim@#2%
  \expandafter\endcsname
  \expandafter\endgroup
              \the\@tempdima\relax
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{First section}
\subsection{First subsection of first section}
\subsection{Second subsection of first section}

\section{Second section}
\subsection{First subsection of second section}
\subsection{Second subsection of second section}

\tableofcontents

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]